# Get resulting URL in Java

Tags: java, url

Is it possible to get the resulting URL from a given URL? For example

```
System.out.println(realUrl("sourceforge.com"));

private String  realUrl(String url)
{
 ....
}
```

Should print the resulting URL "http://sourceforge.net/", and similarly tinyurls would return the destination URL

Comment: Sorry i misread your question as get the "content" of the URL. Please delete my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can:

- Check if a protocol is present in the string. If not, append `http://`
- Then use an HTTP client (like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)) to open the URL. Then follow redirects (`.setFollowRedirects(true)`) until it stops redirecting. That would be the "final" or "real" URL.

Some example code for HttpClient can be found here:
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/
(See `TrivialApp.java` to get started)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested properly .

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class UrlCon3
  {

    public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        String x="http://tinyurl.com/cys7t";
        while(x!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
            x=getRedirectionUrl(x);
        }

      }

    static String getRedirectionUrl(String x)
    {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try
          {
            URL url = new URL(x);
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
            HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            uc.connect();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
            return(uc.getHeaderField("Location"));
          }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        catch (IOException e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        finally
          {
            try
              {
                if (null != in)
                  {
                    in.close();
                  }
              }
            catch (IOException e)
              {
                // ignore
              }
          }
        return null;
    }
  }
```